# enter key behaviour in wx.grid

Tags: wxpython

I simply want the user to be able to press the enter key to add a new line in a cell in a grid instead of moving to the next cell down
Is this possible, been googling for hours
Using python 3.6 and wxpython phoenix.

appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: sorry for late reply, I've really only been testing the grid control. The key combo of ctrl+enter is really what I was looking for and thought there might be a property to set this to just the enter key. The main reason for the question is that ctrl+enter works perfectly on windows but not really on linux.